# Does printing several journal articles for a friend run afoul of copyright law?

Tags: copyright, fair-use, academia

I am a graduate student. For a fellow graduate student's upcoming birthday, I wanted to give him a collection of seminal papers in his field. The idea was to print a collection of 10 papers, totaling around 300 pages, which would then be assembled into a hardback book.

I am well aware that I do not own the copyright to any of these papers. However, would my gift fit the criteria for fair use?

In the case that this is legal, is there anything I should write in the book regarding copyright, besides attributions?

Here are several additional considerations.

1. I do not intend for this book to be sold. I want to print exactly one copy.
2. In my department, it is common for people to print out hundreds and hundreds of pages of journal articles every week. I know this because I have to wait for them at the printer. Printing this book doesn't feel so different from what my colleagues are already doing, the only difference being that I would bind the pages in a book. Are we all breaking the law?

Comment: Are you both students at the same school? How are you getting these papers, is it from your school's subscription to certain journals?

Comment: We are both students at the same school. The papers were obtained from our school's subscription.

Comment: Which country are you in? This is relevant as different countries have special allowances for copyright for the purpose of teaching. For example in Germany ANY book that is not specifically published as material to be used in schools may be freely copied from for teaching within some length limits. For scientific reasons, add a proper citation to each article though, as he can't quote his private anthology in a meaningful way otherwise.